# S3 policy that only allows delete for buckets created by the user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I would like to create a policy that allows all S3 actions, but to only delete the buckets and files the user has created itself. Can I define a condition to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no concept of a "user that created the bucket".

Instead, users request that a bucket be created. IAM then checks whether they have permission to do this, and the bucket is created **on behalf of the account** (*not* on behalf of the user). Therefore, there is no concept of a user that owns/created the bucket.